# How to map a network drive from Windows 7 PC to Windows 10 (or vice/versa)?

Tags: windows-10, home-networking

Folks, I've tried all the things I've searched for but it seems like Windows 10 is outright against mapping drives.

I have a network in my house, (no domain) and all machines belong to the same Workgroup and are on the same subnet. All machines can ping one another by name just fine.

In the past when I'd bring a new Windows 7 machine on, I could map the drive (the admin share, ie c$), using the remote computer's creds.  That *always* worked and I could navigate my machines without issue.  Until I made the mistake of taking Microsoft's bait and trying Windows 10 on one of them.

I've tried the network settings both "use usernames to share folders", and the "let windows manage..." and neither work.

And it's not just mapping from a 7 machine to a 10 machine--I can RDP into the 10 machine just fine, but when trying to map a drive back to my machine (which I can do from any other computer in the house), the Windows 10 machine says "Cannot find the device computername\D$.  The "computername" pings just fine.  Windows 10 refuses to acknowldege any admin root share.   I don't even get a chance to give a user/pwd.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Far more extensive googling found this:

1. Open Regedt32

2.Expand the tree to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft\ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ policies \ system.

3.Create a new key (Right click -> New -> choose “DWORD Value (32bit)”).
4.Name the key “LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy” and give it the value of “1”. Click OK.